# Is there a timeout for idle PostgreSQL connections?

Tags: postgresql, database-connection

```
1 S postgres  5038   876  0  80   0 - 11962 sk_wai 09:57 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres my_app ::1(45035) idle                                                                                 
1 S postgres  9796   876  0  80   0 - 11964 sk_wai 11:01 ?        00:00:00 postgres: postgres my_app ::1(43084) idle
```

I see a lot of them. We are trying to fix our connection leak. But meanwhile, we want to set a timeout for these idle connections, maybe max to 5 minute.

Comment: how are you connecting to the DB? socketTimeout might be what you are looking for.

Comment: We have this legacy Pylons web app, and we used SQLAlchemy but apparently we didn't use it properly. I don't remember. We are trying to fix the leak. `socketTimeout` from the doc it looks like this close the connection to the DB, entirely. I am trying to close each idle, and the counter starts as soon as the connection is established.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391174/is-it-possible-to-configure-postgresql-to-automatically-close-idle-connections

Comment: @user1012451 When you say "close each idle" - do you mean terminate `<IDLE> in transaction` sessions, leaving the session running but in `<IDLE>` state? In other words, terminate the transaction but not the session? (Downvoted: unclear question)

Comment: @CraigRinger after a while, we reach max client connection. To solve that, we must restart the webapp, which forces to restart postgresql as well. That wipe out every connection. When we see these `idle` forever, we are asking if we could set a timeout on each connection/session (I honestly don't know the correct terminology, sorry). If a transaction takes 5 minutes for a normal web app something must be wrong....

Comment: what about something like auto-reconnect?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

It sounds like you have a *connection leak* in your application because it *fails to close pooled connections*. You aren't having issues just with `<idle> in transaction` sessions, but with too many connections overall.

Killing connections is not the right answer for that, but it's an OK-ish temporary workaround.

Rather than re-starting PostgreSQL to boot all other connections off a PostgreSQL database, see: [How do I detach all other users from a postgres database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6122/7788) and [How to drop a PostgreSQL database if there are active connections to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408156/how-to-drop-a-postgresql-database-if-there-are-active-connections-to-it) . The latter shows a better query.

For setting timeouts, as @Doon suggested see [How to close idle connections in PostgreSQL automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12391174/398670), which advises you to use PgBouncer to proxy for PostgreSQL and manage idle connections. This is a very good idea if you have a buggy application that leaks connections anyway; I *very strongly* recommend configuring PgBouncer.

A [TCP keepalive](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html) won't do the job here, because the app is still connected and alive, it just shouldn't be.

In PostgreSQL 9.2 and above, you can use the new `state_change` timestamp column and the `state` field of `pg_stat_activity` to implement an idle connection reaper. Have a cron job run something like this:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
    FROM pg_stat_activity
    WHERE datname = 'regress'
      AND pid <> pg_backend_pid()
      AND state = 'idle'
      AND state_change < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE;
```

In older versions you need to implement complicated schemes that keep track of when the connection went idle. Do not bother; just use pgbouncer.

Comment: Good, but it will kill other PgAdmin backends. Use additional condition application_name=''

Comment: Can I run pg_terminate_backend if I'm using pgbouncer?

Comment: @HenleyChiu I don't see why not, though I haven't specifically checked.

Comment: Running this seems to have killed my WAL sender process

Comment: @CraigRinger even a psql connection is considered as idle connection. And why does one has to close the idle connection at first place. I have a long running code that establish connection with pg perform some dml operation and the then wait for the message over queue and then perform some more dml operation.Now during that period i.e while it is waiting over queue(for message) as mention above even then the connection with postges is `idle`. why should i close it.

Comment: consider adding this at your 'state' matching: 

`state in ('idle', 'idle in transaction', 'idle in transaction (aborted)', 'disabled')`

Comment: One question, how does pgbouncer help here? We saw connection leaks when GCP did kill our preemptible machines, somehow postgres didn't clean up the connection. How does pgbouncer clean those stale connections up?

Answer (score 85):

In PostgreSQL 9.6, there's a new option [`idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT) which should accomplish what you describe. You can set it using the [`SET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) command, e.g.:

```
SET SESSION idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = '5min';
```

Comment: It sucks having to ask something so simple but I'm brand new to databases in general - Could you please give a very basic example of how to use this function?

Comment: Anything like this in previous versions of PostgreSQL??

Comment: No, something akin to the other answers is required for previous versions.

Comment: Do you need to set this parameter at every restart of database? Or after you did once you can forget about? Thanks

Comment: `SET SESSION` is just for the current session (it will go back to the default once you open a new connection). You can also set config parameters on a database level using e.g. `ALTER DATABASE SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = '5min'`, or using configuration files (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html).

Comment: or you can set in **postgresql.conf** or via [alter system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersystem.html).  Very nice.

Comment: You can also set this on a DB level:
`ALTER DATABASE <DB name> SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout TO '5min';`

Comment: Note that this would *not* kill `state = 'idle'`. It would only kill session you see as `state = 'idle in transaction'`. And it is a good thing. Because when you have connection pooling you will have a lot of idle connections and those would probably not be a problem.

Answer (score 23):

In PostgreSQL 9.1, the idle connections with following query.  It helped me to ward off the situation which warranted in restarting the database.  This happens mostly with JDBC connections opened and not closed properly.

```
SELECT
   pg_terminate_backend(procpid)
FROM
   pg_stat_activity
WHERE
   current_query = '<IDLE>'
AND
   now() - query_start > '00:10:00';
```

Comment: pg_terminate_backend is in since 8.4

Answer (score 13):

if you are using postgresql 9.6+, then in your postgresql.conf you can set

`idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 30000` *(msec)*

Answer (score 6):

There is a timeout on broken connections (i.e. due to network errors), which relies on the OS' TCP keepalive feature. By default on Linux, broken TCP connections are closed after ~2 hours (see `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time`).

There is also a timeout on abandoned transactions, `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` and on locks, `lock_timeout`. It is recommended to set these in `postgresql.conf`.

But there is no timeout for a properly established client connection. If a client wants to keep the connection open, then it should be able to do so indefinitely. If a client is leaking connections (like opening more and more connections and never closing), then fix the client. Do **not** try to abort properly established idle connections on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround that allows to enable database session timeout without an external scheduled task is to use the extension [pg_timeout](https://pgxn.org/dist/pg_timeout/0.0.1/) that I have developped.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is set this value "tcp_keepalives_idle". Check more in documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-connection.html.