# How we can configure postgresql 9.2 to close connections older then some time interval?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, perl

I am using `postgresql` version 9.2 which does not support the configuration parameter `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`. I have a `perl` script which is giving below error and I can see there are open connection processes which are in ideal state for more then few days. I want to close this open connections.

> failed: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already at GA/MiddleTier/Pg.pm
>   line 72

I have set `max_connections = 200` in my postgresql.conf file. Please help how this can be achieved.

Comment: You should be using some form of connection pooling. If not in your Perl code, then you could use [PgBouncer](https://pgbouncer.github.io/) or [Pgpool-II](http://www.pgpool.net/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a timeout for idle PostgreSQL connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236160/is-there-a-timeout-for-idle-postgresql-connections)

Comment: If you are looking for help on how to handle the connection on the perl side, I would suggest that you provide a sample of your current code and how you expect it to behave.

Comment: This is more like a environment issue as I have upgraded to RHEL 7.5 and PostgreSQL 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL will kill active connections:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'database_name'
AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```