# DBCP connection pool settings on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-commons-dbcp

I use a connection pool on tomcat for my java web application.
Connections tomcat created was not what I had in mind.
Do I misunderstand properties initialSize, maxTotal, maxIdle, minIdle ?

Tomcat 8.0.48/PostgreSQL 9.4.9

My connection pool setting on Tomcat is;

```
<Resource name="jdbc/postgres_test" auth="Container"
           type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
           url="jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/sss_test"
           username="sss_test"
           password=""
           initialSize="10"
           maxTotal="10"
           maxIdle="10"
           minIdle="0"
           maxWaitMillis="10000"
           testOnBorrow="true"
           validationQuery="select 1"
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"/>
```

Then I checked connections by sql on psql, It was like below,
(same as using netstat command)

```
sss_test=> SELECT count(client_addr) FROM pg_stat_activity group by client_addr;
   client_addr  | count
  --------------+-------
   A            |    30
```

I expected 10 connections but it was 30.

Comment: Are they **active** connections? what is your query?

Comment: Rather than printing the count, what does the `client_addr` look like - same?

Comment: @user7294900 They were all idle connections. It was just after server started.

Comment: @Scary Wombat Sorry, I edited my sql it was wrong, client_addr was same!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236160/is-there-a-timeout-for-idle-postgresql-connections

Comment: It was my mistake that the connection pool setting is in context.xml on the tomcat conf directory. I have 3 applications and it was loaded for each applications. Thanks, both!