# Connections not being closed(HikariCP, Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker-swarm, hikaricp

## Env

Spring Boot 2.1.2.

2 environments: `local`(postgres 11) and `qa` (docker swarm with postgres 10 and application)

## Problem

After `maxLifetime` passes, hikari recreates connections(closes old ones and creating new ones), but on `qa` environment connections are not getting closed: checking with `select * from pg_stat_activity wheredataname=...`
and in logs we have:

```
2019-09-25 12:00:20.694 DEBUG 6 --- [nnection closer] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@54d41592: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-09-25 12:00:20.699 DEBUG 6 --- [onnection adder] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@29e14ddb
2019-09-25 12:00:26.372 DEBUG 6 --- [nnection closer] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@11684c62: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-09-25 12:00:26.376 DEBUG 6 --- [onnection adder] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@453f8d6c
2019-09-25 12:00:28.130 DEBUG 6 --- [nnection closer] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1b2ef2bc: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-09-25 12:00:28.135 DEBUG 6 --- [onnection adder] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@4bf86bbb
2019-09-25 12:00:28.459 DEBUG 6 --- [nnection closer] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@34fbeadd: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-09-25 12:00:28.464 DEBUG 6 --- [onnection adder] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@4fc7e61c
2019-09-25 12:00:31.962 DEBUG 6 --- [nnection closer] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@40771fc4: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-09-25 12:00:31.966 DEBUG 6 --- [onnection adder] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@ac56180
2019-09-25 12:00:35.600 DEBUG 6 --- [nnection closer] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@65cae248: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2019-09-25 12:00:35.607 DEBUG 6 --- [onnection adder] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@33a8d959
2019-09-25 12:00:35.649  WARN 6 --- [   scheduling-1] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@15e91fa9 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2019-09-25 12:00:35.650  WARN 6 --- [   scheduling-1] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@11d699cc (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2019-09-25 12:00:35.651  WARN 6 --- [   scheduling-1] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3883b6a6 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2019-09-25 12:00:35.652  WARN 6 --- [   scheduling-1] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@230234a5 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2019-09-25 12:00:35.657 DEBUG 6 --- [nnection closer] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@15e91fa9: (connection is dead)
2019-09-25 12:00:35.657 DEBUG 6 --- [nnection closer] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@11d699cc: (connection is dead)
2019-09-25 12:00:35.657 DEBUG 6 --- [nnection closer] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3883b6a6: (connection is dead)
2019-09-25 12:00:35.658 DEBUG 6 --- [nnection closer] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@230234a5: (connection is dead)
2019-09-25 12:00:35.674 DEBUG 6 --- [onnection adder] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3b85c924
2019-09-25 12:00:35.678 DEBUG 6 --- [onnection adder] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@4b022f4e
2019-09-25 12:00:35.686 DEBUG 6 --- [onnection adder] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6aea9ecf
2019-09-25 12:00:35.691 DEBUG 6 --- [onnection adder] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1ffdf0da
```

## Question:

Why connections are not getting closed?

**Edit:**
Hikari config:

```
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : HikariPool-1 - configuration:
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : allowPoolSuspension.............false
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : autoCommit......................true
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : catalog.........................none
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : connectionInitSql...............none
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : connectionTestQuery.............none
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : connectionTimeout...............30000
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : dataSource......................none
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : dataSourceClassName.............none
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : dataSourceJNDI..................none
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : driverClassName................."org.postgresql.Driver"
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : healthCheckProperties...........{}
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : healthCheckRegistry.............none
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : idleTimeout.....................600000
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : initializationFailTimeout.......1
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : isolateInternalQueries..........false
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:postgresql://postgres/db
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : leakDetectionThreshold..........0
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : maxLifetime.....................1800000
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : maximumPoolSize.................10
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : metricRegistry..................none
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : metricsTrackerFactory...........none
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : minimumIdle.....................10
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : password........................<masked>
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : readOnly........................false
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : registerMbeans..................false
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : scheduledExecutor...............none
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : schema..........................none
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : threadFactory...................internal
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : transactionIsolation............default
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : username........................"username"
 c.z.h.HikariConfig  : validationTimeout...............5000
 c.z.h.HikariDataSource  : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
 c.z.h.p.HikariPool  : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@53fd0d10
 c.z.h.HikariDataSource  : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
 o.f.c.i.d.DatabaseFactory : Database: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/db (PostgreSQL 10.10)
```

Comment: @user7294900 Absolutely same code on local and qa, default hikari configuration(updated my answer).
Regarding closing connections in code - i'm using jpa, so i don close them explicitly.

Comment: @user7294900 I don't use PGBouce, Hibernate core version 5.3.7.Final

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Solved by setting `maxLifetime` to 10 minutes.*

**Explanation:**
It turns out docker swarm somehow drops idle connection. So, when hikari closes connection, nothing reaches postgres, so from postgres standpoint there is still a connection. 10 minutes is less that default docker idle connection timeout, so connections are closed properly.

Comment: Yes, it's 900 seconds IPVS default idle timeout. More information on the issue with Docker (Swarm / K8S) and IPVS here: https://success.docker.com/article/ipvs-connection-timeout-issue

Comment: Does anyone know what is the counterpart configuration of HikariCP's `maxLifetime` on the database side? I'm guessing it is `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` for Postgres but I'm not sure.

Comment: @emrekgn Here's what I found for the Postgres side of the Hikari problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13236160/501113