# How to close idle connection on PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I've been accessing a postgreSQL database with python3 and psycopg2.

I encountered an error that implied I had open connections. When I ran `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity` a bunch of connections under my username came up. They all have a state of 'idle', and many of them show a "query" value that I never ran (ex: `select 1`, `show search_path`).

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391174/how-to-close-idle-connections-in-postgresql-automatically) on how to close them automatically. And, I've also read that using `pg_terminate_backend` is dangerous and will cause the database to restart. How do I close these connections naturally with python3 or SQL? It is a company production database, so restarting it or being the admin isn't an option. Let me know if I must be an admin to solve this issue.

Comment: i have the same problem, i'm using c3p0 and there's lots of `idle` connection in `pg_stat_activity` and the number keeps growing. Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely terminate your own idle backend processes using `pg_terminate_backend(pid int).` If you try to terminate a process you haven't access to, you'll get an error message and nothing special will happen. Don't try to terminate active processes.

[Per the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html):

> pg_terminate_backend(pid int)
>
> Terminate a backend. This is also allowed if the calling role is a member of the role whose backend is being terminated or the calling role has been granted pg_signal_backend, however only superusers can terminate superuser backends.