# How to shut down idle connections to Postgres DB in Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, amazon-rds

We have a Postgres database set up in the RDS. I wrote some APIs to handle data ingestion to the db using Spring Boot. Recently I discovered that lots of connections kept their sessions alive after calling the APIs. Some of the sessions date back to 3 months ago.

I wonder if there is a way to automatically close these connections after it's been inactive for a while. From [How to close idle connections in PostgreSQL automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391174/how-to-close-idle-connections-in-postgresql-automatically), looks like I can set up a cron job to look for dead connections with a SQL query and terminate them with `pg_trminate_backend`. Is this the best option? Is there something that can be done in the web application layer? Or maybe some RDS parameters? Need some advice on this.

Answer (score 8):

**from 9.6 on**, you have:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html

> `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` (integer)
>
> Terminate any session with an open transaction that has been idle for
>   longer than the specified duration in milliseconds. This allows any
>   locks held by that session to be released and the connection slot to
>   be reused; it also allows tuples visible only to this transaction to
>   be vacuumed. See Section 24.1 for more details about this.
>
> The default value of 0 disables this feature.

(formatting mine)

**before 9.6**- yes the only native way - cron with `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE now()-state_change > '5 minute'::interval`.

**also** if you use connection pooling with **pgbouncer**, then:

https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html

> `server_idle_timeout` If a server connection has been idle more than
>   this many seconds it will be dropped. If 0 then timeout is disabled.
>   [seconds]
>
> Default: 600.0

(formatting mine)

Comment: I set `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` to 60 seconds. It does not seem to affect any of the sessions that have been idle for 2 months though. Had to manually terminate these legacy sessions. Hopefully, it will apply to new sessions that become idle in the future.

Comment: you can check it, by opening connection and not running any query for two minutes

Comment: I know this is five years old, but `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` doesn't apply to idle sessions unless they're in an incomplete transaction.