# Releasing JDBC connections after kubernetes pod is killed

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-data-jpa

I am running a couple of spring boot apps in Kubernetes. Each app is using spring JPA to connect to a Postgresql 10.6 database. What I have noticed is when the pods are killed unexpectedly the connections to the database are not released.

Running `SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database;` on the database returns lets say 50, after killing a couple of pods running the the spring app and rerunning the query this number jumps to 60 this eventually causes the number of connections to postgresql to exceeds the maximum and prevent  restarted pod's applications connecting to the database.

I have experimented with the postgresql option `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` setting it to 15s but this does not drop the old connections and the number keeps increasing.

I am making use of the `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource` datasource for my spring apps and was wondering if there was a way to prevent this from happening, either on the posgresql or spring boot's side.

Any advise or suggestions are welcome.

Spring boot version: 2.0.3.RELEASE
Java version: 1.8
Postgresql version 10.6

Answer (score 0):

This issue can arise not only with kubernetes pods but also with a simple application running on a server which is killed forcibly ( like `kill -9 pid` on Linux) and not given opportunity to process to clean up via a shutdown hook to spring boot. I think in this case nothing on the application side can help. You can however try cleanup of inactive connections by several methods on database side as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391174/how-to-close-idle-connections-in-postgresql-automatically/30769511).