# handle shutdown of Java AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

Is there a way to hook into a Lambda's shutdown? I am opening a database connection and want to keep it open, but I want to make sure it gets closed when the Lambda is terminated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cleaning up after AWS Lambda execution context is closed with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60546259/cleaning-up-after-aws-lambda-execution-context-is-closed-with-python)

Comment: Why is your Lambda getting terminated before it's able to cleanly close the connection?

Comment: @stdunbar I want to do some basic connection pooling in the Lambda so I don't need to open a connection on each request.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably interested in an event that is thrown when the Lambda instance is being killed and not when a single invocation ends, right? You have one option for both though, but I doubt that they'll help you..

You can either use the context method [`getRemainingTimeInMillis()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html) (links to Node.js but similar in other programming languages) to find out when the current invocation of your Lambda function times out. This might be helpful to cleanup things or use the time of your Lambda function to the full extent. I **don't recommend** to cleanup your database connections at the end of each invocation because then you won't reuse them for future invocations which slows down your Lambda function. But if you're okay with that, then go for it. Remember that this only works as long as your function is running. As soon as you have returned a response, you can't perform any cleanup operations because your Lambda function will get into a 'sleep mode'. You need to do this before you return something.

Alternatively, you can make use of the [Extensions API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-extensions-api.html). It offers a **shutdown phase** and triggers an extension with a `Shutdown` event. However, since an extension sits *besides* your function (and not within your function code), I'm not sure if you have a chance to clean up any database connections with this approach... See also [Lambda Execution Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html) for additional information.

Comment: Yeah, when it is killed. I read about the Extensions API but I'm not using a custom runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a pooled connection for a warm lambda, you may register a shutdown hook to close the DB connection or release any other resources, you only have 500 ms to perform this task.

```java
class EnvironmentConfig {

    private static volatile boolean shutdownRegistered;
    private static volatile HikariDataSource ds;

    private void registerShudownHook() {
        if (!shutdownRegistered) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (!shutdownRegistered) {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
                        if (ds != null) {
                            ds.close();
                        }
                    }));
                    EnvironmentConfig.shutdownRegistered = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        HikariDataSource _ds = EnvironmentConfig.ds;
        if (_ds == null) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                _ds = EnvironmentConfig.ds;
                if (_ds == null) {
                    _ds = new HikariDataSource();
                    // TODO: set connection props
                    EnvironmentConfig.ds = _ds;
                    registerShudownHook();
                }
            }
        }
        return _ds;
    }

}
```

You can reference the datasource anywhere to get a singleton copy which will create the instance and register the shutdown hook.

Your shutdown hook could do other tasks, provided it does them quickly, or you can register more than one hook, just don't go nuts with how many threads you're registering.

Answer (score 0):

**No, you can't hook into the shutdown of a Lambda Execution context.**

Lambda handles that on it's own an decides if and when to re-use or destroy execution contexts.

You'll probably have to rely on the connections to time out on their own.