# I would like to set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout for a Heroku Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391174/how-to-close-idle-connections-in-postgresql-automatically/30769511#30769511) I would like to change the idle_in_transaction_session_timeout in Heroku Postgres, however I do not have the rights as a superuser (see [Heroku default permissions](https://help.heroku.com/IV1DHMS2/can-i-get-superuser-privileges-or-create-a-superuser-in-heroku-postgres)). Are there any alternatives to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it for your own user:

```
alter user current_user set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = '5min';
```

Comment: I am not sure this is working. If I run ```show idle_in_transaction_session_timeout;``` it still shows me 0 and all the sessions that are idle in transaction haven't been terminated after 5 minutes.

Comment: I think you need to disconnect and re-connect. Existing sessions won't be affected as far as I know